# Parse error in Android 5.0 , working in previous versions

Tags: android

I have an apk to download from a website. It works fine in Android 4, but when I downloaded it with an Android 5.0 device, I got the typical error:

**Parse Error
There was a problem while parsing the package**

Can anyone shed a bit of light on what is happening?

My server code to get the apk file (I don't want to place the apk file directly to download in website):

```
InputStream is = ApkDownloadController.class.getResourceAsStream("/apk/fileName.apk");
        try {

        response.addHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=apkName.apk");
        response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        // copy binary contect to output stream
        while (is.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        is.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Need more info..Does it work in the emulator? Have you tried side loading the APK from SD card?

Comment: @Ed_Fernando I placed the apk directly in SD and works fine. But when its downloaded from the server, fails. Only in Android 5. :(
I dont use the emulator, I´ll try it and will comment. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code for downloading the apk? It could be that the buffer is not big enough. Some other issues that can cause this error: Does the device allow installing from unknown sources? Is the apk signed? Do you have anything in the manifest limiting what devices it is allowed on?